# Excel : Selecting data and keeping it up to date

Tags: excel

Ugh,

I'm not a hero when it comes to Excel...
I have an Excel file with one sheet that contains all data. It's basically a list of tickets, displaying the ticket ID, type, value and 5 dates per row.

I'm looking for a way to have new sheets in the Excel that actually display only tickets of a specific type. So on the sheet *Bug Tickets* I want to diplay like a filtered sub-set of the raw data in the first sheet.

However, this new sheet needs to refresh it's data automatically when I add new data to the main list.
Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You can try using a pivot and of course this is very doable using VBA. That is AFAIK.

Comment: I'll look into Pivot tables. Never used this before...

Comment: See my post which I hope doesn't confuse you. It can't really be called as answer but unfortunately, it won't fit as comment. Also, I voted to move your question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) where your questions about a lot of things in excel can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a way using a *Pivot Tables* and *Tables*.
You should set it up like below: (in the SS, I put the pivot in the same sheet but you can put it in another).

[image]

**Steps:**

You need to create a table out of your data. [*See here on how to do it*](http://contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html).
Then create a *Pivot Table* out of your table. [*See here on how to do it*](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-excel-2010.html)

After that you just need to format it the way you want.
The *Pivot table* will update everytime you add data on your table.
It will display what you've filtered.(in my example I filtered type **A**).

**Notice:** Apologies I cannot create a step by step procedure for you(very tedious). I wouldn't have posted this as answer if only it would fit as comment.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Now just playing with the formatting.

Comment: @NekoNova Oh cool :) Just play a bit on `Pivot Options` specially on *Layout & Format, Totals & Filters and Display* tabs. In my example, I uncheck most of the items in there to remove dropdowns, collapse/expand buttons, grand totals, auto-fitting columns etc. so it would look like a normal range. :)

Comment: got the layout now I want, was a bit tricky since I need to look up how it's all called in German....
Is there a way to blend out the "value" part of the Pivot table, because that's empty anyway

Comment: @NekoNova By blend out you mean remove? Of course. It's up to you to decide :)

Comment: yeah. Right now I hid the columns, which also works tbh ;)
Thanks for all the help ^^